# Generate Setup.exe for ClickOnce application using msbuild

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, publish, setup.exe

Publishing the ClickOnce application via `msbuild` using command

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:BootstrapperEnabled=true;PublishDir=C:\publish\;PublishUrl=C:\publish
```

Throws the error:

> error MSB3484: Signing target 'bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe' could not be found.
>
> No setup.exe is generated, whereas publishing via Visual Studio IDE generates the setup.exe to the specified folder.

Have looked over the net and found the below solutions

1. To enable `BootstrapperEnable = true`,
2. To specify `\` at the end of `PublishDir`/`PublishUrl`

And the above solutions don't work for me. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked:

msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishDir=C:\publish\ /p:ApplicationVersion=1.0.1.1

Din't have to specify the InstallationFolder, since ClickOnce takes up the folder path from where the user installed the setup.exe as the InstallFolder and looks there for updates.